# Loopback 4 controller Omit<T,K>

Tags: typescript, loopback, loopback4

I'm giving my first steps in Loopback 4, and I've been trying to follow the tutorial that they have to generate a new REST Api.
The thing is that after creating my model, database and repository, I started to develop my controller class and encountered a piece of code that nowhere in the documentation we have a mention to it.

I have it signaled below:

```
async createTodo(
    @requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: getModelSchemaRef(Todo, {title: 'NewTodo', exclude: ['id']}),
        },
      },
    })
 todo: **Omit<Todo, 'id'>,** <----------
  ): Promise<Todo> {
    ...
    return this.todoRepository.create(todo);
  }
```

My question is: For what this omit is for? I've tried to remove it from the code, and the result is the same as the one that I have without it.

Also, in that post request, I'd like to hide the id property from the object, when I receive the answer. How can I do that just for this request' response?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is more `Typescript` thing than `Loopback`.

Loopback uses Typescript so you usually define types and interfaces. For controller request body, you need to define interface.

> **`Omit<T,K>`**
>
> Constructs a type by picking all properties from `T` and then removing `K`.

Here, I assume you have set id property to auto generate or generate by yourself. And `id` property is not a user input. Your front-end does not send `id` value. Then You need to create an interface with all properties of `TodoModel` except `id`. Now you can create new record with the received object.

You can read more on Typescript utilities [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk)

In addition, `Loopaback4` uses `DataObject<Model>` to convert model into interface.